# Open Visual Studio from within Git bash

Tags: visual-studio, git-bash

I want to open Visual Studio Editor from within the git bash. Don't know why but providing the path doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me, when I put single quotes around the path and use git path syntax. I just dragged devenv into the console to get the path and hit enter.

```
'/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/Common7/IDE/devenv.exe'
```

[image: git bash launching devenv.exe]

Answer (score 4):

It's much more simpler:

```
$ start MySolution.sln
```

This starts the default program for the specified file.

Comment: simplest answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I added an alias to my `~/.profile` file:

```
alias studio='"/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/devenv.exe"'
```

So I can easily open any solution from the shell:

```
$ studio MySolution.sln &
```

The `&` at the end sends the Visual Studio process to background so that the shell does not get blocked by Visual Studio and Visual Studio won't be ended when I close the shell window.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open Visual Studio Code within GIT Bash, and you want to open the the project which you are currently working on, type the following command:

```
code .
```

If you only want to open Visual Studio Code within GIT Bash (which will open the a previous project that you were working on), type the following command:

```
code
```

Answer (score 1):

One Option is using 
`start *.csproj` 
when inside of the the folder for the solution in git bash. It is going to open all files with the .csproj extension but since there should only be one it will open that single project workspace.